# Linux VLC subtitles - qestionmarks instead of several characters

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player, encoding, subtitles

While watching movie using VLC with czech subtitles, qestionmarks appears instead of some (ěščřž etc.) characters. Steps that I have tried so far:

- Converting subtitles from windows-1250 to utf-8 using iconv:

  iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t UTF-8 1250.srt > utf8.srt

I assume that conversion was successful because when I open windows-1250 version (with vim or gedit) I saw strange characters, after conversion to utf-8 subtitles looks OK, so it seems that that from/to format was chosen correctly.

- Setting various combinations in VLC player "default encoding" font and subtitles settings.

I guess that something is wrong with language support on system wide level or something similar.

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload a sample Czech subtitle file so I can check it?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14673239/utf8.srt
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14673239/1250.srt

Answer (score 2):

No need to convert the subtitle file. Try this:
open VLC, go to `Tools > Preferences > Subtitles & OSD` and under `defualt encoding` change the encoding to `Eastern European (Windows 1250)`

*(you said you have tried some combinations, but I don't know which ones)*

Comment: I have tried 1250, 1252 and of course utf-8 with same result.

Comment: It should work with 1250. Try to restart VLC. meanwhile, I'm downloading [this](http://www.podnapisi.net/ppodnapisi/podnapis/i/1456538/in-time-2011-titulky) subs just to check, but since I don't know Czech at all I will upload a screenshot of the subtitles.

Comment: Yep, I've changes the default encoding to 1250 and restarted VLC and it seems fine to me - please confirm. [Image](http://i.imgur.com/QIz8avA.jpg) (ignore the movie, I checked just the subtitles).
**Note:** Before I've change the encoding to 1250 it was gibberish, like you have mentioned.

Comment: Yes your subtitles looks OK, I have exactly the same VLC settings with font "Nimbus Sans L" I do not understand.

Comment: It may be issue with the font itself, maybe it's not mapped to Czech. Try with the `Arial` font. Remember to restart VLC!

Comment: Bro, there is no arial on Linux :) so far I have made it following way (simply removes accents): iconv -f WINDOWS-1250 -t ascii//TRANSLIT 1250.srt

Comment: Oh, right. One can't remember everything, right?
However, try to use another font or use Arial with [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-microsoft-core-fonts-in-ubuntu-linux/) tutorial. For as far as I can think, the problem must be with the font since the encoding works.

Comment: Maybe, but I have tried several another (not Arial) and when I type with "Nimbus Sans L" in LibreOffice the accents works fine.

Comment: Still, try with Arial. The problem must be there..
Also make sure you have the latest version if VLC installed.